# Foliation with leaves which are and are not dense

Tags: gn.general-topology, foliations, surfaces

Do there exist a foliation on a closed surface (i.e. real dimension 2) which has a dense leaf and also a leaf which is not dense?

Comment: There is a trivial way to do this by taking a foliation with a dense leaf, say of a torus, and puncturing the surface twice along another leaf.

Comment: @DouglasZare You are right, but by a surface I mean a compact surface without boundary.

Answer (score 11):

No, there doesn't exist such a foliation. The existence of any foliation would mean the Euler characteristic is zero, so the surface must be either a torus or a Klein bottle. Foliations for these surfaces are understood well enough to rule out having both dense and non-dense leaves.

Any foliation will contain a "Reeb component" (for which no leaf is dense) or will be a suspension of a homeomorphism of $S^1$. If a circle homeomorphism has one dense orbit, all orbits are dense, so the situation you describe can't exist.

If you allow surfaces with boundary, you need to consider a Mobius band or annulus, but it's still not possible to have a dense and non-dense leaf: the foliation will have pieces that are either Reeb components or suspensions of interval homeomorphisms, neither of which can have a dense leaf.

For the definition of a Reeb component and complete details, see this page, especially the "Foliations of Surfaces" section:
http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Foliations